# changing the button movement on scroll using css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried a lot and have reached till here. what wrong is going on i don't understand. where i am missing. please see to it. I want the button request a proposal to change its position form horizontal to vertical when we scroll down.I want that css class .vertical-pos and .head__get-in-touch-wrap to change by function. Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
    
    var span = $(".head__get-in-touch-wrap");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
           span.removeClass('head__get-in-touch-wrap').addClass("vertical-pos");
        } else {
          span.removeClass("vertical-pos").addClass('head__get-in-touch-wrapr');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
body {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.main-menu {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: -90px 235px 0 0 !important;
  list-style: none;
  transition: opacity .6s 2.5s;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar--inverted .main-menu__item {
  color: #000;
}
.main-menu__item {

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font: 400 15px/20px 'Oswald',sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.main-menu__item--request {
  border:1px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:0;
  padding:15px 30px;
}
.main-menu__item > a {
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: 700;
}
a {
  background-color:transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:active, a:hover {
  outline:0;
 color:#C1C1C1;
}
.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  display: none;
  width: 44px;
  height: 56px;
  background: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 4% 0 20px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  align-items: flex-start;
  }
.menu-toggle:hover{
   color:#C1C1C1;
} 
.logo{
   margin:20px;

} 
.main-block__line {
  background:#171717;
  display:none;
  height:5px;
  left:5%;
  margin-left:15px;
  position:absolute;
  top:550px;
  width:20px;
  z-index:10;
}
.head__menu-btn__wrap {
  display:block;
  margin:-25px -40px 0 0;
  position:fixed;
  right:5%;
  top:47px;
  width:226px;
  z-index:999;
}.head__menu-btn {
  -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease;
  background-image:url(../pixster/menu-btn.png);
  background-position:0 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:45px 45px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  height:45px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  transition:all 0.1s ease;
  width:45px;
  z-index:999;
}
.head__get-in-touch-wrap {
  -webkit-transform-origin:203px 23px 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s!important ;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.39, -0.16, 0.4, 1.21)!important ;
  display:block;
  height:45px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute !important;
  top:0;
  transform-origin:203px 23px 0;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.39, -0.16, 0.4, 1.21);
  width:146px;
   
}
.vertical-pos{
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
.head__get-in-touch {
  -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease;
  background-color:#0072F6;
  border:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  display:block;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:600;
  letter-spacing:2.5px;
  margin-top:0;
  padding:15px 0;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  transition:all 0.1s ease;
  width:146px;
}
```

```html
<header class="logo">
<img src="../pixster/logo.png" alt="Pixster Studio" />
</header>
<span class="main-block__line">
</span>
<div class="head__menu-btn__wrap">
<span class="head__menu-btn open-main-menu-button">
</span>
<span class="head__get-in-touch-wrap">
<a href="/contact" class="head__get-in-touch">Request a proposal</a>
</span>
</div>
<ul class="main-menu in-view">
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/work">Work</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
    <button data-menu-button="" type="button" class="menu-toggle">
                    <span class="menu-toggle__lines"></span>
                </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/p3x9k67d/

Change the **css** to:

```
.head__get-in-touch-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin:203px 23px 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s!important ;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.39, -0.16, 0.4, 1.21)!important ;
  display:block;
  height:45px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute !important;
  top:0;
  transform-origin:203px 23px 0;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.39, -0.16, 0.4, 1.21);
  width:146px;  
}
```

**JS to :**

```
$(function() {

    var span = $(".head__get-in-touch-wrap");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 10) {
           span.addClass("vertical-pos");
        } else {
          span.removeClass("vertical-pos");
        }
    });
});
```

**snippet code :** ignore

```js
$(function() {
    
    var span = $(".head__get-in-touch-wrap");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 10) {
           span.addClass("vertical-pos");
        } else {
          span.removeClass("vertical-pos");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
body {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.main-menu {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: -90px 235px 0 0 !important;
  list-style: none;
  transition: opacity .6s 2.5s;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar--inverted .main-menu__item {
  color: #000;
}
.main-menu__item {

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font: 400 15px/20px 'Oswald',sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.main-menu__item--request {
  border:1px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:0;
  padding:15px 30px;
}
.main-menu__item > a {
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: 700;
}
a {
  background-color:transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:active, a:hover {
  outline:0;
 color:#C1C1C1;
}
.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  display: none;
  width: 44px;
  height: 56px;
  background: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 4% 0 20px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  align-items: flex-start;
  }
.menu-toggle:hover{
   color:#C1C1C1;
} 
.logo{
   margin:20px;

} 
.main-block__line {
  background:#171717;
  display:none;
  height:5px;
  left:5%;
  margin-left:15px;
  position:absolute;
  top:550px;
  width:20px;
  z-index:10;
}
.head__menu-btn__wrap {
  display:block;
  margin:-25px -40px 0 0;
  position:fixed;
  right:5%;
  top:47px;
  width:226px;
  z-index:999;
}.head__menu-btn {
  -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease;
  background-image:url(../pixster/menu-btn.png);
  background-position:0 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:45px 45px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  height:45px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  transition:all 0.1s ease;
  width:45px;
  z-index:999;
}
.head__get-in-touch-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin:203px 23px 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s!important ;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.39, -0.16, 0.4, 1.21)!important ;
  display:block;
  height:45px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute !important;
  top:0;
  transform-origin:203px 23px 0;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.39, -0.16, 0.4, 1.21);
  width:146px;
   
}
.vertical-pos{
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
.head__get-in-touch {
  -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease;
  background-color:#0072F6;
  border:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  display:block;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:600;
  letter-spacing:2.5px;
  margin-top:0;
  padding:15px 0;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  transition:all 0.1s ease;
  width:146px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="logo">
<img src="../pixster/logo.png" alt="Pixster Studio" />
</header>
<span class="main-block__line">
</span>
<div class="head__menu-btn__wrap">
<span class="head__menu-btn open-main-menu-button">
</span>
<span class="head__get-in-touch-wrap">
<a href="/contact" class="head__get-in-touch">Request a proposal</a>
</span>
</div>
<ul class="main-menu in-view">
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/work">Work</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
    <button data-menu-button="" type="button" class="menu-toggle">
                    <span class="menu-toggle__lines"></span>
                </button>
```

Comment: dear your fiddle is what i want but when i am trying in my code it is inot working..what is wrong

Comment: I have made the small changes in your code.see the JS and add `display: inline-block;` for class `head__get-in-touch-wrap`.

Comment: there may be a chance the your screen not scroll upto `50px` and your if condition is not execut

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed also check if any error in your console

Answer (score 0):

try add to the span an id attribute, so you can reach it more clearly,the id stays while you change the class

```
<span class="head__get-in-touch-wrap" id="foo">
```

also attach the scroll event to the window with on():

```
var span = $("#foo");
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
       span.removeClass('head__get-in-touch-wrap').addClass("vertical-pos");
    } else {
      span.removeClass("vertical-pos").addClass('head__get-in-touch-wrapr');
    }
});
```